# Xcode : Adjust UICollectionViewCell top position

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionviewcell, nslayoutconstraint

I want to set top position of UICollectionViewCell so that extra spacing is removed.

Trying to set top position at design time but it is disabled.

[image: Screenshot 1]

At runtime top position is set to 0 then too there is lots of empty spaces.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath:NSIndexPath ) -> CGSize {

       . . .

        if device_type == "iPhone4-Series" {
            mElementSize = CGSizeMake(60, 60)
        }
       . . .
    }

   func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: NSInteger) -> CGFloat {

        if device_type == "iPhone4-Series" {
           return 5.0
        }
    . . .
   }

  func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: NSInteger) -> CGFloat {

        if device_type == "iPhone4-Series" {
            return 5.0
        }
     . . .
   }

   func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout:UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAtIndex section: NSInteger) -> UIEdgeInsets {

        if device_type == "iPhone4-Series" {
            return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,40,2,40)
        } 
    . . .
 }
```

[image: Screenshot 2]

[image: Screenshot 3]
How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to look at these properties in UICollectionViewFlowLayout:

- minimumLineSpacing
- minimumInteritemSpacing
- sectionInset